# How to get simple ForeignKey model working? (a list of class in another class)

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I tried to figure this out on my own :( couldn't quite get there.  Pls take pity. . .

I'm trying to represent exercise data (a start time an end time and many--an undetermined number of-- heart rates)

this is the model I have set up:

```
class HeartRate(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField('Date and time recorded')
    heartrate = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return prettyDate(self.timestamp)

class Exercise(models.Model):
    start_timestamp = models.DateTimeField('Starting time')
    finishing_timestamp = models.DateTimeField('Finishing time')
    heartrate = models.ForeignKey(HeartRate)
```

I know from working with the admin that it seems only one HeartRate is selected for each Exercise so maybe my approach is all wrong.  How do I correctly model this?  And once modeled correctly how do I query all heart rates for each (all) Exercises.  I know this is a noob move but I really tried for hours getting this to work and can't quite get a handle on the documentation.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "only one HeartRate is selected for each Exercise "?

Comment: It seems only one heart rate is attributed to each exercise out of a list of choices.  (there is a list of the heart rates and one with a checkmark by it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should reverse the foreign key relationship:

```
class HeartRate(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField('Date and time recorded')
    heartrate = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, related_name='heartrates')    

class Exercise(models.Model):
    start_timestamp = models.DateTimeField('Starting time')
    finishing_timestamp = models.DateTimeField('Finishing time')
```

To get all of the heartrates of an exercise:

```
heartrates = my_exercise.heartrates.all()
```

Comment: I think, nima, there's a typo fourth line should read: ForeignKey(Exercise, . . .